# Frequent anaconda-mode buffers pop-up with "No such file or directory"

Tags: spacemacs, python, osx, anaconda-mode

Running spacemacs on OSX. Using Anaconda.

Every few keystrokes in a .py file, a buffer will pop up in anaconda-mode (which I have tried to disable with `M-x anaconda-mode`)

> /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs-x86_64-10_9:
>   path-to-project/venv/bin/python: No such file or directory

The minibuffer displays this message:

```
Cannot create ~/.emacs.d/.cache/anaconda-mode/0.1.7/ directory
```

This directory does exist.

I created the project on the command line with

```
conda create --name name-of-project-venv
```

The behavior basically makes spacemacs unusable for editing Python files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution I've found is to simply open spacemacs from within the virtualenv.

This isn't super satisfying, because I don't want to have to open separate emacsen to work on different projects, so I'm adding this answer but not accepting it for now, in hopes of a better solution.